# Asignar defaultValue a Autocomplete de Material-UI ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hola estoy utilizando el componente "[Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/)" de Material-UI y no sé como poder asignarle a cada opción un value, *queda como value el "tittle", como puedo hacer que el value sea el "year"*.

Por ejemplo si selecciono 'The Godfather' el value queda como 'The Godfather', entonces como se puede hacer para que el value quede como '1972'

```
import React from 'react';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete';

export const ComboBox =() => {
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      id="combo-box-demo"
      options={top100Films}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
      style={{ width: 300 }}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Combo box" defaultValue="The Godfather" variant="outlined" />}
    />
  );
}

// Top 100 films as rated by IMDb users. http://www.imdb.com/chart/top
const top100Films = [
  { title: 'The Shawshank Redemption', year: 1994 },
  { title: 'The Godfather', year: 1972 },
  { title: 'The Godfather: Part II', year: 1974 },
  { title: 'The Dark Knight', year: 2008 } 
]
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con "queda como value el tittle pero quieres ir el year". Me perdí ahí =/

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera por ejemplo si selecciono 'The Godfather' el value queda como  'The Godfather', entonces como se puede hacer para que el value quede como '1972'

Answer (score 0):

Si miras la **[documentación](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#autocomplete)** del componente Autocomplete, te darás cuenta que sólo te faltaba enlazar el `value` a algún `state` y manejar el evento `onChange`

```
<div className="App">
   <Autocomplete
   value={data}
   onChange={(event, newValue) => {
     setData(newValue);
   }}
   id="combo-box-demo"
   options={top100Films}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.title}
   style={{ width: 300 }}
   renderInput={(params) => 
      <TextField 
         {...params}  
         label="Combo box" 
         defaultValue="The Godfather" 
         variant="outlined" 
      />}
/>
```

Nos comentas si fue lo que necesitabas :D